# Gaussian distribution: moments, independence and rotation

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, moments, rotation

I have a few questions with respect to the gaussian distribution, its moments and independence.

So a gaussian distribution is fully specified by its first two moments, the mean and variance (or covariance matrix in the multivariate case). Since uncorrelatedness means unrelated in the first two statistical moments and independence means unrelatedness in all higher moments as well, the jointly gaussian distributed variables are independent if they re uncorrelated.

My question now is, what does it mean that it is fully specified by its first two moments? I mean the higher order moments are not zero? Can someone maybe also give a counter example, so how it looks if a distribution is not fully specified by its first two moments?

And another questions relates to the rotational invariance of the gaussian. For independent component analysis one demands that the latent variables are not gaussian distributed because the gaussian can -apparently - only be defined up to a rotation. What exactly does that mean and does it have anything to do with its property that it is fully specified by its first two moments?

Comment: Given the first two moments, one can write down the density of the distribution.

Comment: but doesnt this apply to almost all distributions? I mean the first moment is the mean of the distribution and the second moment is the variance+mean². And e.g. the Bernoulli distribution has mean $\pi$ which is also its only parameter and can therefore also be directly written down by knowing even only the first moment

Comment: This is true of many distributions and hence not a property unique to the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Statistical terminology in these matters is awful, because many writers use the word "distribution" to refer *either* to (a) the distribution function of a random variable or (b) a *family* of such distributions.  Your questions move about between the two senses, potentially creating much confusion.  In particular, "fully specified by its first two moments" is a concept that can *only* apply to a family and it merely means there is a one-to-one correspondence between the first two moments and a parameter for the family. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320746 for more.

Answer (score 2):

Distributions that involve more than two parameters are rarely characterised by their first two moments. An example is the [g-and-k distribution](https://rdrr.io/cran/gk/man/g-and-h.html), which quantile function
$$q_{A,B,c,g,k}(z) = A + B [1 + c \tanh(gz/2)] z \exp(k z^2/2)$$
involves five parameters. Among other characteristics, it does not enjoy a closed-form cdf or pdf (but they can be [numerically approximated](https://statisfaction.wordpress.com/2017/06/11/likelihood-calculation-for-the-g-and-k-distribution/)). Another extreme example is when considering the set of all probability distributions on $\mathbb{N}$, which are indexed by an infinite sequence $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

The rotational invariance of the Normal distribution is restricted to the case of an iid vector with mean zero, $X\sim\mathcal{N}_d(0_d,I_d)$ since $RX\sim \mathcal{N}_d(0_d,R R^\text{T})$.

Comment: Thank you. How does this property, that the gaussian is fully defined by its first two moments, lead to the fact that if jointly gaussian variables are uncorrelated they are also statstically independent? So would this apply also for all other distributions that are characterized by their first two moments?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?^^

Answer (score 0):

> My question now is, what does it mean that it is fully specified by its first two moments? I mean the higher order moments are not zero?

While it is true that the normal distribution has an infinite number of higher-order moments, what makes it special is that it is the only distribution with a finite number of *cumulants*. Specifically, Marcinkiewicz (1935) showed that the normal distribution is the only distribution whose cumulant generating function is a polynomial, i.e. the only distribution having a finite number of non-zero cumulants.

The cumulant generating function for $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is
$$
K_X(t)=\log M_X(t)=\mu t+\sigma^2 t^2/2=\kappa_1t+\kappa_2t^2/2.
$$
Through the use of Faa di Bruno's formula the moments of the normal distribution become can be expressed in terms of the cumulants by
$$
\mathsf EX^n=\sum _{k=1}^{n}B_{n,k}(\kappa _{1},\ldots ,\kappa _{n-k+1}).
$$
What this shows is that once you know the mean $(\mu)$ and the variance $(\sigma^2)$ all other higher-order moments of the normal distribution are determined; thus it is characterized by these first two moments.