# What does it mean when a distribution is "INDEXED" by something?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, terminology

I am doing some reading and am seeing phrases such as the following.  For context, I am learning about Bayes Inference and prior/posterior distributions so theta is the parameter:

> In such problems, we shall refer to the distribution **indexed** by θ for
>   the other random variables of interest as the conditional distribution
>   for those random variables given θ.

...

> In many problems, such as Example 7.2.1, the observable data X1, X2, .
>   . . are modeled as a random sample from a univariate distribution
>   **indexed** by θ.

...

> In these cases, let f (x|θ) denote the p.f. or p.d.f. of a single
>   random variable under the distribution **indexed** by θ.

What does "indexed" mean and how do I conceptualize it?

Comment: This is essentially the same question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320746, only using the term "index" rather than "parameter."