Concept of complete sufficient statistic for the cdf $F(x)$
I am studying Hogg and McKean's "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics." At the end of section $7.7$ where they talk about completeness, sufficiency etc for multi-parameter case, theny mention (specifically in example $7.7.5.$) that given the order statistics $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of a random sample $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are known, the conditional distribution is independent of the cdf $F(x)$. Then they mention

Hence, by the definition of sufficiency, the order statistics are sufficient for $F(x)$.

I am having trouble understanding this statement. So far, sufficiency was defined for the parameters of the distribution from which the random samples are drawn. So in the definition of sufficiency (definition $7.2.1$) for instance, the authors mention

... Then $Y_1$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ ..."

where $f(x;\theta)$ is the pdf or pmf from which the samples were drawn. Now out of the blue, we are talking about sufficient statistic for the cdf. This was never defined.
If you put a gun to my head, I'd have substantiated it by saying that "since the conditional distribution does not depend on the cdf, it cannot depend on any of the parameters that are used to define the cdf." But it is still unsettling to me that without giving formally defining it, the authors, out of the blue, are talking about "sufficient statistic for the cdf."
Is this obvious to you? How exactly is sufficiency defined, now that I have learnt that we can also have "sufficient statistic for the cdf."? Most importantly, how is completeness and sufficiency defined so that it will work for cdf/pdf/parameters alike?

In a nonparametric setting, the distribution itself is unknown. Hence you see "sufficient for cdf". Even in a parametric setting, when you say "sufficient for $\theta$", it means "sufficient for the family of distributions parameterized by $\theta$".

Thanks @StubbornAtom for the information. To their credit, the authors do mention in the text that "For our last example, we consider a case where the set of parameters is the cdf." Don't you think though, that they must have formally defined what it means when they are referring to sufficient statistic for the cdf? I mean how exactly do you consider cdf as the set of parameters?

Mathematically, any family of distributions can parameterize itself (that's a triviality arising from the definitions).

Don Fraser (Toronto) wrote extensively on this general notion of sufficiency.

@Xi'an Thanks for the information. I will surely look it up.

@whuber Sir. Thanks for the information. So the way you parameterize any family is by forming a map from the set of parameters to the family of distributions? In this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/320801/183497 towards the end, you have mentioned "The family of all finite-variance absolutely continuous distributions is not parametric." So will that be an exception to your statement "any family of distributions can parameterize itself"? Kindly clarify.

"Parametric" does not mean "can be parameterized:" instead, it means the parameter space is finite dimensional (and its dimension does not change with the sample size).

So in this textbook, the parameters have always been finite in number. When they define sufficiency, they simply say "conditional distribution is independent of $\theta \in \Theta$". All their examples thus far have been pertaining to cases where there are two or at the most, three parameters. However, it does not look like there is any such stipulation on $\theta$ (for it to be finite dimensional or not) when we define sufficiency.

A statistical experiment is constituted by the triplet $(\mathscr X, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, \mathfrak M),$ where $\frak M$ is a family of probability measures on $(\mathscr X, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}) .$ Based on the sample $X,$ one has to draw inference about the true distribution which is unknown and is a member of $\mathfrak M. $
A statistic $T:(\mathscr X,\boldsymbol{ \mathfrak A}) \to_m (\mathscr Y,\boldsymbol{ \mathfrak B})$ is sufficient for $\frak M$ if, for each $A\in\boldsymbol{ \mathfrak A}, $ there exists a $T^{-1}(\boldsymbol{ \mathfrak B}) /\mathfrak B_{\mathrm{l\! R}}$–measurable function $\kappa_A:\mathscr X\to_m\mathrm{l\!R}$ such that for each $P\in\mathfrak M, $ almost surely  $$P(A\mid T) =\kappa_A,$$
(or there exists a function $\eta_A:\mathscr Y\to_m\mathrm{l\!R}$ such that for each $P\in\mathfrak M, $ almost surely  $$P(A\mid T) =\eta_A\circ T $$).
$\kappa_A$ is same for all $P\in\mathfrak M. $ The motivation is that the information provided by $T$ that is, $\sigma(T), $ is sufficient for inferring about the possible distribution $P;$ one doesn't know which $P$ is the true distribution among the $P$s in $\frak M$ and thus the definition needs to hold for all $P\in\mathfrak M$ otherwise any dependence of $\kappa_A$ for a particular distribution would have defeated the objective of reduction of information sufficient for inference of the true distribution.
The family $\frak M$ is not specified; in case of parametric family, $\mathfrak M=\{P_\theta\mid \theta\in\Theta\}, $ $\Theta$ being an index set. So, inferring about $P_\theta$ is akin to inferring about $\theta, $ provided the family is identifiable.
Detailed explanations, treatments of various foundational aspects of sufficiency and relevant references have been dealt in this post, this post and this one.

Thank you for the answer and for sharing all the information with me. Can you please recommend a text which treats mathematical statistics at this level of rigor?

I would suggest you to look into my other post that I linked; that has ample materials referenced. Depends on what you are comfortable with. Hogg's book is a pretty decent text for beginners -- remember one cannot learn every advanced thing in a single go, rather learning happens in a phased manner. Meanwhile I have noticed few typo in my answer; would fix that.

Yup. It has ample reference books in there. Thank you!

The likelihood for a sample of $n$ independent and identically distributed observations $x_i$ can be partitioned in a part that is dependent on the order statistics $y_{(i)}$ and the parameters, and a part that depends on the data without the parameters.
$$f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n; \theta) = \prod_{i}^n g(x_i;\theta) = \underbrace{h(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}_{\substack{\text{a part that depends on data $x_i$}\\\text{but without influence from $\theta$} }}\cdot \underbrace{\prod_{i}^n g(y_{(i)};\theta)}_{\substack{\text{a part that only depends}\\\text{on the statistics $y_{(i)}$ and $\theta$} }}$$
namely, this function $h$ is just unity
$$f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n; \theta) = \prod_{i}^n g(x_i;\theta) = \prod_{i}^n g(y_{(i)};\theta)$$
therefore the order statistics are sufficient.
Given the order statistics, the dependency of the likelihood on the parameters is not dependent on any more information, and it is sufficient to know the order statistics.
The likelihood is just a product of the individual likelihoods and the ranking of the different observations is irrelevant. The parameters have no influence on the ranking.

Is $h=1$ or the $g(y_{(i)};\theta)=1$? I am asking that because there are no parameters in this case. We just have a bunch of realizations, and we get their order statistics. The authors claim this order statistic is sufficient for the cdf. I am used to hearing sufficient for the parameter $\theta$ but now, there is no mention of any parameter. We are now looking at just the cdf as that in and of itself is like a parameter. So I'd think that $g=1$ and not $h$.

I did some reading (basically graduate mathematical statistics and they say that family of distributions can be parameterized if and only if there can be a one-to-one mapping between the set of parameters $\Theta$ and the family of distributions $P$, where $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ for a finite positive integer $d$. So in case we cannot parameterize, then we cannot even talk about $g(y_{(i)};\theta)$ right?

It is $h=1$. The parameters that I refer to is $\theta$. The parameterisation can be the values of the CDF in every point.

Example: whether you observe {1,2} vs {2,1}, their relative probabilities don't depend on the parameter. Therefore, based on the ranking of the observations you cannot infer anything about the parameters.

If $\theta$ has values of cdf at every point, then it has infinite points in case of continuous cdf case. How exactly do you represent $\theta$ if it has infinite points? If it is a normal distribution, mean and variance will fix the cdf. Understood. But if it is a cdf that does not have a parametric representation, how exactly do you define $\theta$ in that case?

Honestly, I fail to understand from you description as to how the statement "is sufficient for the cdf" is justified. As I mentioned previously, there may not be a parametric representation of the family of cdf so we may not even be able to include $\theta$ in our argument. The premise is that there is a family of distributions (call it $P$ or whatever else you'd like). Given that there is no one-to-one mapping from a finite dimensional set like $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $P$, where $d$ is a finite positive integer, how exactly do you substantiate the statement "is sufficient for the cdf"?

@TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr I don't think that you have to take that 'sufficient for the cdf' so litteral. Sufficiency is a property in relation to a model, not in relation to the CDF (although in some cases the CDF itselve can be the parameters, e.g. think of a categorical distribution where cdf and parameters have a one to one relationship). Possibly they meant that the order statistics are sufficient to describe the empirical distribution function. And since the empirical distribution is sufficient, therefore also the order statistics are significant.
