# Exponential Family Representation: Dumb question on scale parameter and whether it went to Hawaii

Tags: distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

So going over the Hastie Tibshirani paper on GAM - it points to equation 11 as the exponential family density - but with two parameters - theta (natural parameter) and phi (scale).

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177013604
$$
p(x;\theta,\phi) = \exp \left\{ \frac{[\theta \cdot x−A(\theta)]} {a(\phi)} +c(x,\phi) \right\}
$$
where $\cdot$ is a dot product and $c$ and $a$ are functions.

Whereas I am more familiar with the location only representation - see for example [Definition of exponential family](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129990/definition-of-exponential-family)

$$
p(x;\theta) = h(x) \exp( \theta \cdot T(x)−A(\theta)) 
$$
where $\cdot$ is a dot product.
What is going on? its likely the difference between density and distribution with the phi parameters defining the normalizing constant.

Would like some details or a reference would be most appreciated.
Observations:

1. The $c(x,\phi)$ is $c(x)$ or basically $h(x) = \exp(c(x))$ and $a(\phi) =1 $. No idea why x became T(x)
2. Note the derivative of the cumulant $A(\theta)$ in each equation is equal to the expected value of x and T(x) respectively. WHich indicates the two are not equivalent.

Comment: A handy Mathjax reference can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference in case you ever need a hint!